# Jump to the top of a command line output gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I'm developing c++ projects with Ubuntu's terminal and have found myself scrolling to the top of long error output after failed make attempts. Is there a way to jump to the location of the last command (eg make) or to the top of an output? For example, if file the_hobbit.txt contained the contents of Tolkien's glorious book and I entered:

> $ cat the_hobbit.txt

what is the easiest way to jump to the beginning of the book?

Thanks